# iphone any interface to deal with sqlite database created in the application Documents folder?

Tags: iphone, ios4, sqlite

do we have any command line from where i can query the sqlite database, which is created by coding, and stored in the application's default Documents folder?

Comment: What is wrong with this question? Why down vote?

Answer (score 1):

Turn on file sharing for the app, copy the database file to your Mac, and use the command line tools (sqlite3) that are there.

(Note to the previous editor: I appreciate editing of answers for accuracy, format improvements, and fixing typos...but, if you want to provide completely different information, I suggest providing your own answer instead of changing the meaning of another user's response.)